# Al generar el APK el Mapa no se muestra en la actividad Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-play

Tengo un problema que no logro solucionar. **Cuando genero un `apk signed` de mi aplicación de Android Studio el contenido principal** (Que es un fragment de un mapa) **no se muestra**, pero cuando simplemente corro la app para probarla todo se ve bien. **Que podra ser?**

**Adjunto imagenes:**

Sin Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Lo que puede estar sucediendo es que necesites generar la huella digital SHA1 para el modo lanzamiento. 
Puedes encontar información específica si accedes con tu cuenta a la **consola de google cloud platform**, posteriormente accede al menú **API y servicios>credenciales** Una vez que accedas a esta sección debes seleccionar el api key que hallas configurado en tu app.

A continuación seleccionar la opción **Apps de android** (que se encuentra en el apartado **Restricciones de aplicaciones**) cuando selecciones esta opción aparecerán una serie de pasos y un comando que debes ejecutar en tu eqipo para obtener el SHA1 (asegúrate que sea el indicado para el modo lanzamiento), una vez que tengas el SHA1 lo registras en la sección denominada **Restringir uso para tus apps de Android** también te solicitará el nombre del paquete de tu aplicación.

Por supuesto esta es una respuesta muy resumida, quizá debas de cumplir algunos mas requisitos para ejecutar los comandos en tu equipo, pero espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario Jesus, pero no era lo que buscaba. Asi todo ya pude solucionarlo!